# Write an SQL query that reports the number of posts reported yesterday for each report reason

Tags: sql

I'm doing the following leetcode question on SQL. The solutions given by others (as what follows) are more or less the same, and I didn't understand why they're correct, since in my opinion, there might be 2 reports with the same reasons, same post_id but by different user_id:

```
There is no primary key for this table, it may have duplicate rows.
```

Did I understand correctly?

```
-- Question 43
-- Table: Actions

-- +---------------+---------+
-- | Column Name   | Type    |
-- +---------------+---------+
-- | user_id       | int     |
-- | post_id       | int     |
-- | action_date   | date    | 
-- | action        | enum    |
-- | extra         | varchar |
-- +---------------+---------+
-- There is no primary key for this table, it may have duplicate rows.
-- The action column is an ENUM type of ('view', 'like', 'reaction', 'comment', 'report', 'share').
-- The extra column has optional information about the action such as a reason for report or a type of reaction. 
 

-- Write an SQL query that reports the number of posts reported yesterday for each report reason. Assume today is 2019-07-05.

-- The query result format is in the following example:

-- Actions table:
-- +---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+
-- | user_id | post_id | action_date | action | extra  |
-- +---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+
-- | 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | view   | null   |
-- | 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | like   | null   |
-- | 1       | 1       | 2019-07-01  | share  | null   |
-- | 2       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
-- | 2       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | report | spam   |
-- | 3       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
-- | 3       | 4       | 2019-07-04  | report | spam   |
-- | 4       | 3       | 2019-07-02  | view   | null   |
-- | 4       | 3       | 2019-07-02  | report | spam   |
-- | 5       | 2       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
-- | 5       | 2       | 2019-07-04  | report | racism |
-- | 5       | 5       | 2019-07-04  | view   | null   |
-- | 5       | 5       | 2019-07-04  | report | racism |
-- +---------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+

-- Result table:
-- +---------------+--------------+
-- | report_reason | report_count |
-- +---------------+--------------+
-- | spam          | 1            |
-- | racism        | 2            |
-- +---------------+--------------+ 
-- Note that we only care about report reasons with non zero number of reports.

-- Solution
Select extra as report_reason, count(distinct post_id) as report_count
from actions
where action_date = DATE_SUB("2019-07-5", INTERVAL 1 DAY) and action='report'
group by extra

or

SELECT extra AS report_reason, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) AS report_count
FROM Actions
WHERE action_date = '2019-07-4' AND action = 'report' 
GROUP BY extra
```

If I understood correctly, the solution would be like this, right?

```
with x as (
select distinct * from actions)
select extra as report_reason, count(*) as report_count
from x
where action='report' and action_date = '2019-07-4'
group by extra
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct * from actions will return two rows for post 4 where action is `report` because user_id is not same for both the report

But to count post per report reason you need to use count(distinct post_id) to count unique post_id.

So this will be better answer.

```
SELECT extra AS report_reason, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) AS report_count
FROM Actions
WHERE action_date = '2019-07-4' AND action = 'report' 
GROUP BY extra
```

But if you really want to select distinct in common table expression you can select distinct rows for `post_id,action_date , action,extra` instead of all

```
with x as (
select distinct post_id,action_date , action,extra from actions)
select extra as report_reason, count(*) as report_count
from x
where action='report' and action_date = '2019-07-4'
group by extra
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I understood now, they asked for the number of posts reported for each report reason, so even it's reported from different users, we will count it only once. We only count it twice or more if it's reported for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two users can do same raport like user 2 and 3 with post 4. In my opinion good query will be:

```sql
WITH "distinct reasons for post" AS (
  SELECT extra AS report_reason
  FROM actions
  WHERE action = 'report' and action_date = '2019-07-04'
  GROUP BY post_id, extra
)

SELECT report_reason, COUNT(1) AS report_count
FROM "distinct reasons for post"
GROUP BY report_reason
```